# get activity inside of static class

Tags: android, static

I have a class which extends `Asynctask`  and I want to access my activity or context of it. Every time I try, I get ***cannot be referenced from a static context*** or ***Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application***.

ps: I'm not using fragments, it's only activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be careful when passing context in an async task; you could create leaks. You can interact with your activity in an async task if you create a weak reference to it when you declare your task and acquire the reference when you need to use it by calling .get() on it.

```
private static class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    Private WeakReference<YourActivity> weakReference;

    YourAsyncTask(YourActivity context) {
        weakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

        …

    @Override
    Protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        YourActivity activity = weakReference.get();
    }

}
```

Comment: this error is thrown when I try to execute Asynctask class: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: @Paya You'd have to add all the relevant code, in order for us to troubleshoot it better.

Comment: I found that problem. Thank you so much for helping with the context.

Comment: @Paya I'm glad you were able to figure it out. Thank you for accepting the answer!